# Get single value using orderby clause in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Hello I am very new in LINQ and I want to implement the below query in LINQ:

```
select top 1 Registrationid from registration order by datemodified desc
```

With the above query I want to return the latest updated registrationid.

Can anyone please tell me the syntax of the above query to write in **LINQ**

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

```
var result = _dbcontext.Registrations.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateModified);
```

I tried many more syntaxes but at the end the above seems to be more appropriate to me, but with the above syntax I am unable to get the single sorted **registrationid**

Comment: It's that urgent so you even don't have time to try implement it?

Comment: I tried this from the past 1 hour and also search on Google thats why I asked here Mr.Sergey

Comment: [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b). You need to look at [Enumerable.FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I think I have added that I am really new in LINQ at the very starting of my question

Comment: @garvitgupta it's OK to be new in LINQ, but what exactly you have tried last hour? Show us, then we'll help you to solve problems you faced, and explain what you did wrong

Comment: @Sergey: I have UPDATE my question with my syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost did it. Just add `FirstOrDefault` to select `TOP 1` entity from database. And project results with `Select` after you sorted them by date:

```
var result = _dbcontext.Registrations
                       .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateModified)
                       .Select(x => x.RegistrationId) // select only id field
                       .FirstOrDefault(); // top 1
```

This query will return latest registration id, or default value (`0` for integer) if there is no registrations.

Generated SQL will look like:

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
[Extent1].[RegistrationId] AS [RegistrationId]
FROM [dbo].[Registrations] AS [Extent1]
ORDER BY [Extent1].[DateModified] DESC
```

Comment: But I think the above syntax will give us the entire row, I also written the same query but I was unable to get the registrationid.
I only want to return the registrationid.

Comment: @garvitgupta sorry, I thought you want entire entity. I'll update answer

Comment: No Prob, I am waiting